# How to change the message "webgroup/virtual host to handle has not been defined"?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

When I stop an application on Websphere 8.5, and try to access the application,
I get the message: `webgroup/virtual host to handle has not been defined` which is normal.

I want to change this message to something else. Is this possible?

Comment: I was hoping for some suggestions too :-). I've definitely wished before that the message when the app was down would be different from when trying to hit, say, a URL where this is no app even installed.

Comment: This has annoyed me for years. Even though we have a maintenance page on our front-end httpd server, there is a brief time when deploying a new version of the application that this message appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution :

open IBM admin console

https://localhost:9043/ibm/console

Navigate to Servers ->Server Types -> WebSphere Application Server -> server1-> Web Container Settings -> Web container -> Custom Properties

Click on New button  to add new properties and fill the  details as given below and Apply and Ok.

Name :   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html#replacingthecontentoferrormessagesrve0017worsrve0255ewithauserdefinedstring)

Value :  Custom Error Message. (For Eg. Server is under maintenance. Please visit after some time)

restart the WAS.

Comment: Presumably, though, it's still the same message for when an app is stopped and when it doesn't even exist?

Comment: @dbreaux, it's for when app is stopped